# The process I execute doesn't finish by itself

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to run an export datapump (expdp) from my app in JAVA. The problem is the expdp process never ends.
The datapump starts, runs and finishes successfully but the process still shows as running in the Windows task manager causing my app to continue executing. It stays waiting for the process to end.

So far, this only happens with this specific process (expdp). I've tried with some .bat scripts and they run perfectly.

```
public class DataPump {
```

`private static Date date = new Date();

static DateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");

private static String comando="expdp";
private static String user="user/***********@DB1";
private static String schemas="schemas=ADMIN";
private static String directory="directory=BACKUPS";
private static String dumpfile="dumpfile=Backup_" + dateFormat.format(date) + "_" + hourFormat.format(date) + ".dmp";
private static String logfile="logfile=Backup_" + dateFormat.format(date) + "_" + hourFormat.format(date) + ".log";
private static String parallel ="parallel=4";

public static void expdp() {
    try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(comando, user, schemas, directory, dumpfile, logfile, parallel).start();

        p.waitFor();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the export datapump finished");
}`

}